# movl AT&T syntax with attributes

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, inline-assembly

Here is a snippet of `assembly code` in `AT&T Syntax`.

```
int foo_array[64*1024]  __attribute__ ((aligned (8192)));

void
foo()
{
    __asm__("movl %0,%%eax"::"r"(&foo_array));
```

I understood that `movl` copies the data from source operand to destination operand. that is, in my case, it is moving `0 to eax`.. This is what I have understood from this [link](http://www.scs.stanford.edu/nyu/04fa/notes/l2.pdf) - `slide 2`

However, I dont understand the rest of it. Can someone please explain it so me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should read up on [GCC inline assembly constraints](http://www.ibiblio.org/gferg/ldp/GCC-Inline-Assembly-HOWTO.html).

In short, what that `::"r"(&foo_array)` says is that you want one input for your assembly code, that the input should be placed in a register, and that its value should be the address of `foo_array`.
The `%0` in the code is substituted with that input, so the code places the address of `foo_array` in `eax`.